# Check all functions checks all checkboxes even disabled ones

Tags: jquery

I've a function that checks all checkboxes I would like to add to it .not(:disabled) but when I added it after the .is an error was thrown. How could I prevent checking disabled checkboxes?

```
function selectAllCheckBoxes( table, checkBoxId )
{
    $( 'input', table.fnGetNodes()).prop( 'checked', $( '#' + checkBoxId ).is( ':checked' ).not(':disabled' )
}
```

Comment: where have you added .not(:disabled)?

Comment: What is the trown error?

Comment: `.is()` returns a boolean.  Add it inside `.is(":checked:not(:disabled)")` or swap it around `.not(":disabled").is(":checked")`

Comment: @MarkBaijens ```$(...).is(...).not is not a function```

Comment: @freedomn-m does not help it still checks even disabled checkboxes.

Comment: Can you provide a working snippet to demonstrate the problem?  eg How are you "disabling" the checkboxes?

Comment: Your `:not(:disabled)` is in *completely the wrong place*.  Let me update my answer

Comment: @freedomn-m I have a `var shouldBeDisabled = obj[3] === 'Yes' : 'disabled' : '';` then I add this as variable to hardcoded html in javascript that creates checkbox this works fine, but the check all does not.

Comment: @freedomn-m as I said this is dynamic disabled depending on the json object value it works fine when I enter on the page I have enabled checkbox if not equals Yes and disabled if equals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> added it after the .is an error was thrown

`.is` returns a boolean, so you can't then chain a jquery filter function to it.

This will give an error:

```
$(..).is(":checked").not(":disabled")
```

However, this is only partially the issue as your requirement is:

> How could I prevent checking disabled checkboxes

so the `:disabled` check needs to go against the checkboxes that you're checking, not the one that you're using to check if they should be checked

ie, here:

```
$('input').not(":disabled").prop(...
```

Updated code

```
function selectAllCheckBoxes(table, checkBoxId)
{
    $('input', table.fnGetNodes())
        .not(":disabled")
        .prop('checked', $('#' + checkBoxId).is(':checked')
}
```

Comment: Works fine! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As said Is returns a boolean. Since you don't use the boolean you can consider using filter instead.

```js
$('input').filter(':checked' ).not(':disabled').each(function(){
  console.log($(this).attr('id'))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="checkbox1" type="checkbox" checked disabled>
<input id="checkbox2" type="checkbox" checked>
<input id="checkbox3" type="checkbox" checked disabled>
<input id="checkbox4" type="checkbox" checked>
```